# How to read XML attributes and store into string?

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing

I have Web Drivers path stored in the following XML file. I would like to convert the xml file and store the values into a string. For example, when the string value equals `"chrome"`, it should launch the browser by loading the path stored in the XML file associated with the string. I don't want to use WebDriverManager.

**The XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebDrivers>
    <WebDriver name="Chrome">C:\Users\QA\Maven\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe</WebDriver>
    <WebDriver name="FireFox">C:\Users\QA\Maven\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe</WebDriver>
    <WebDriver name="Edge">C:\Users\QA\Maven\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe</WebDriver>
</WebDrivers>
```

**BasePage Class method**

```
public WebDriver Init_Browser(Properties prop) {
    String browser = prop.getProperty("browser");

    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        tldriver.set(new ChromeDriver()); // tl = thread local concept
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        tldriver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")) {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        tldriver.set(new EdgeDriver());
    } else {
        System.out.println(browser + " browser not defined");
    }
    getDriver().manage().window().fullscreen();
    getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return getDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to use JAXB, you can unmarshal your XML to java objects and after you can create your properties based on those java objects :

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class WebDrivers {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "WebDriver")
    private List<WebDriver> WebDrivers;

    // Getters and Setters
}

@XmlElement(name = "WebDriver")
public static class WebDriver {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    private String path;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```